# How to enable TabNine semantic completion in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

`TabNine` is a deep-learning-based extension that helps in coding. As said in the [doc](https://tabnine.com/semantic) we should type in `TabNine::sem` to enable semantic completion in the text editor, I did not get it. Where and how to run this command on order to enable that feature?

Answer (score 3):

You have to type TabNine::sem directly in the same place you type your code, but in new line and press enter.

```
function yourfunction(){
[...your code here...]
}
TabNine::sem
```

Answer (score 1):

There are good docs, official:
[TabNine Semantic Completion](https://www.tabnine.com/semantic)

To get semantic completion working:

**Type TabNine::sem** to enable semantic completion **in your text editor**.
If you don't see any message, then semantic completion is working.

Verify you are running TabNine 1.0.5 or above by typing TabNine::version **in your text editor**. If you're running an earlier version, try restarting your editor.